# MySQL SELECT same column with multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 'messages' table which includes the columns:

`message_id, sender_id, receiver_id`

And a 'members' table which includes the columns:

`id, username`

My outbox query is as follows

```
SELECT message_id, username AS 'receiver_username', sender_id,
receiver_id, time_sent, time_read, replied_to_id,item_id_reference,
subject FROM messages, members WHERE messages.sender_id = members.id 
AND members.username = ?
```

I want my query to return the `message_id` based on the senders `username`

```
WHERE messages.sender_id = members.id AND members.username = ?
```

but also the recipients username based on the returned `receiver_id`

How would I go about doing this in a single query?

Comment: can you provide sample data and expected results, it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: He wants to get members.username twice: once ON members.id = messages.sender_id, and again ON members.id = messages.receiver_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to join the member table twice, once for the sender name and once for the receiver_name.
A simple example:

```
SELECT
    s.user_name sender,
    r.user_name receiver
FROM
    messages m
JOIN
    members s ON
    m.sender_id = s.member_id
JOIN
    members r ON
    m.receiver_id = r.member_id
```

Comment: I think you left out the ON after the aliases in your JOIN clauses

Answer (score 0):

This can be an alternative to joining `members` table twice:

```
SELECT 
  message_id, username, sender_id,
  receiver_id, time_sent, time_read, replied_to_id,item_id_reference,
  subject 
FROM 
  messages msg INNER JOIN  
  members m ON m.id IN (msg.receiver_id, msg.sender_id) 
AND m.username = ?
```